# Failed to submit Spark Application in cluster deploy-mode to a Standalone Spark Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, deployment

I created a Spark cluster on AWS EC2 in **Standalone** mode.
And everything works well in `--deploy-mode client` - I can read from and write to AWS S3.
But in `--deploy-mode cluster`, it always failed.
The command I used looks like:

```
  ./bin/spark-submit  \
    --class ... \
    --master spark://...:7077 \ # I also tried with 6066
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem \
    ... \
    --jars /local/path/to/hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar,/local/path/to/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar \
    --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar:hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar \
    --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar:hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar \
    --verbose \
    /local/path/to/app.jar
```

The error message is:

```
  18/01/17 05:13:39 ERROR ClientEndpoint: Exception from cluster was: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /local/path/to/app.jar
  java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /local/path/to/app.jar
      at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
      at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
      at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
      at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.copy(UnixCopyFile.java:526)
      at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.copy(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:253)
      at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:1274)
      at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$copyRecursive(Utils.scala:625)
      at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.copyFile(Utils.scala:596)
      at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:681)
      at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:480)
      at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner.downloadUserJar(DriverRunner.scala:155)
      at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner.prepareAndRunDriver(DriverRunner.scala:173)
      at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner$$anon$1.run(DriverRunner.scala:92)
```

According to the official Spark doc [Submitting Applications](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management)
, it should be possible to let `spark-submit` upload my jars to the cluster automatically by specifying `--jars`, and I don't need to do it by myself. But seems it doesn't work as expected.

I also tried to put the `app.jar` to AWS S3, which led to another issue `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found`; I also tried to let `spark-submit` upload the hadoop-aws jars for me via `--jars`, but still failed.

Yes, I can scp these jars to the cluster by myself. I just want to know, what's wrong with my usage. Could anyone please give me some help on this?